# Getting user input from HTML with JS

Tags: javascript, html

My friend and I aree trying to get values from input fields in HTML and use console.log() to print it out so we know we have the data.

However, when we run this it prints out undefined.

html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>
            PyHelp | Register
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css">
        <script src = '../script.js'></script>
    </head>
    
    <body> 
        <header class = 'header'>
            <a href = 'settings.html'> <img class = 'settings' src="../images/settings-icon.png" alt = "settings"> </a>
            <button class = 'login'> <a href = 'login.html'>
                Login
            </a>
            </button>
            <button class = 'createAccount'> <a href = 'createAccount.html'>
                Register
            </a>
            </button>
        </header>

        <div class = 'toolbar'>
            <a href = '../index.html'> <img class = 'logo' src = '../images/pyhelp-logo.png'></a>
        </div>
    
        <div class = 'Registration'>
            <h1>
                Register an Account
            </h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." class="usernameField">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." class="passwordField">
            <button type="button" onclick="createAccount()">Create</button>
            
            
        <div>
    </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
function createAccount(){
    var username = document.getElementsByName('usernameField').value;
    var password = document.getElementsByName('passwordField').value;
    console.log(username, password);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: As the name `getElementsByName` implies, it will return a list of elements not just a single one.

Comment: (Please go read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/; I removed that pestering from your question title.)

Comment: The code should throw an error, since there are no elements with those names in the HTML.

Comment: Use `document.querySelector('.usernameField').value;`

Comment: Add `id="usernameField"` and the same for password, then use `getElementById()`.

Comment: @UdayHiwarale i have tried this and it st ill doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your mistake is calling getElementsByName, and:

- Not naming the element.
- Returns node list, you need to approach the first one. Or, if you have multiple elements with that name, iterate over the list of nodes returned.

```js
function createAccount(){
    var username = document.getElementsByName('usernameField')[0].value;
    var password = document.getElementsByName('passwordField')[0].value;
    console.log(username, password);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>
            PyHelp | Register
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css">
        <script src = '../script.js'></script>
    </head>
    
    <body> 
        <header class = 'header'>
            <a href = 'settings.html'> <img class = 'settings' src="../images/settings-icon.png" alt = "settings"> </a>
            <button class = 'login'> <a href = 'login.html'>
                Login
            </a>
            </button>
            <button class = 'createAccount'> <a href = 'createAccount.html'>
                Register
            </a>
            </button>
        </header>

        <div class = 'toolbar'>
            <a href = '../index.html'> <img class = 'logo' src = '../images/pyhelp-logo.png'></a>
        </div>
    
        <div class = 'Registration'>
            <h1>
                Register an Account
            </h1>
            <input type="text" name="usernameField" placeholder="Type something..." class="usernameField">
            <input type="text" name="passwordField" placeholder="Type something..." class="passwordField">
            <button type="button" onclick="createAccount()">Create</button>
            
            
        <div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any elements with the name attribute set to 'usernameField' and 'passwordField' - you are using 'class' rather than 'name'.

Also getElementsByName returns an array - so you would need to supply an index for it work. e.g.

```js
function createAccount(){
    var username = document.getElementsByName('usernameField')[0].value;
    var password = document.getElementsByName('passwordField')[0].value;
    console.log(username, password);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>
            PyHelp | Register
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css">
        <script src = '../script.js'></script>
    </head>
    
    <body> 
        <header class = 'header'>
            <a href = 'settings.html'> <img class = 'settings' src="../images/settings-icon.png" alt = "settings"> </a>
            <button class = 'login'> <a href = 'login.html'>
                Login
            </a>
            </button>
            <button class = 'createAccount'> <a href = 'createAccount.html'>
                Register
            </a>
            </button>
        </header>

        <div class = 'toolbar'>
            <a href = '../index.html'> <img class = 'logo' src = '../images/pyhelp-logo.png'></a>
        </div>
    
        <div class = 'Registration'>
            <h1>
                Register an Account
            </h1>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." name="usernameField">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." name="passwordField">
            <button type="button" onclick="createAccount()">Create</button>
            
            
        <div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change you script.js createAccount function to:

```js
function createAccount(){
    var username = document.getElementsByClassName('usernameField')[0].value;
    var password = document.getElementsByClassName('passwordField')[0].value;
    console.log(username, password);
}
```

You should have the values printed to console.

What you did wrong:

- To use the getElementsByName(), you need to have a name attribute, which you dont, you have a class. So you need to use getElementsByClassName()

Alertnatively,

Add a name attribute to your inputs

Answer (score 0):

The return value of getElementsByName is an array which has no attribute "value".
You should either refer to the result in index 0 or better yet, since you have and want each field to be unique, use getElementById and change name to Id.

```
<head>
    <title>
        PyHelp | Register
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css">
    <script>
    function createAccount(){
var username = document.getElementsByName ('usernameField');
var password = document.getElementsByName ('passwordField');
console.log(username[0].value, password[0].value);}
    </script>
</head>

<body> 
    <header class = 'header'>
        <a href = 'settings.html'> <img class = 'settings' src="../images/settings-icon.png" alt = "settings"> </a>
        <button class = 'login'> <a href = 'login.html'>
            Login
        </a>
        </button>
        <button class = 'createAccount'> <a href = 'createAccount.html'>
            Register
        </a>
        </button>
    </header>

    <div class = 'toolbar'>
        <a href = '../index.html'> <img class = 'logo' src = '../images/pyhelp-logo.png'></a>
    </div>

    <div class = 'Registration'>
        <h1>
            Register an Account
        </h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." name="usernameField" value="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." name="passwordField" value="">
        <button type="button" onclick="createAccount()">Create</button>
        
        
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```